Difficulty Using Internal or Private Types in Swift Protocol Conformance
I'm encountering issues while trying to use internal or private types in Swift protocol conformance. Here's a simplified version of my code:

internal protocol RATIONAL {
    associatedtype rational
    
    static func makeFrac(_ x: Int, _ y: Int) throws -> rational
    static func add(_ r1: rational, _ r2: rational) -> rational
    static func toString(_ r: rational) -> String
}


public struct Rational1: RATIONAL {
    
    // error: Type alias cannot be declared public because its underlying type uses an internal type
    public typealias rational = Rational
    
    internal enum Rational {
        case Whole(Int)
        case Frac(Int, Int)
    }
    
    // error: Method cannot be declared public because its result uses an internal type
    public static func makeFrac(_ x: Int, _ y: Int) throws -> Rational {
        <#code#>
    }
    
    // error: ...
    public static func add(_ r1: Rational, _ r2: Rational) -> Rational {
        <#code#>
    }
    
    // error: ...
    public static func toString(_ r: Rational) -> String {
        <#code#>
    }

    fileprivate func foo(_ x: Int) {
        <#code#>
    }
    
    private func boo(_ x: Int) -> Int {
        <#code#>
    }
    
    
}

I want the Rational enum to be kept only within the module or even to be private, but the rest of the methods that return or use a Rational to be public. If I change the enum declaration to public, everything works fine. How can I achieve this while keeping the enum internal or private?
At this point protocol could be whatever, if that is needed for this code to work. Thanks
BTW, new to this, so any advice is welcome.

You can even remove the typealias if that is creating problems, but associatedtype must be kept.

I'm confused as to what you want to accomplish. You have public functions (eg makeFrac) which return a Rational. How is the compiler supposed to handle an invocation of makeFrac in some other part of your program? Also, I'm pretty sure someone will comment on your non-swifty use of capitalization, but that doesn't have anything to do with your question.

The capital thing is just because I used similar names, and to be easy to distinguish stuff visually. So makeFrac is making Rational, and I thought that if just the typealias is exposed there should be no problem with the rest (so swift somehow will make the conversion from public Rational to internal rational). Now I kind of get what you are saying. That outside you'll have to use rational not Rational? and that's why I get the error?

If that is the case how can I make the enum be internal, and still use public for those methods? Or is the question suppose to be how can I just give a pick to the internal representation of my type and not to enum?

This can't be done, from the documentation: No entity can be defined in terms of another entity that has a lower (more restrictive) access level . Read more here

@JoakimDanielson so for the purpose of understanding this means that is working in reverse? from lower to higher? (In my case I don't think it will be feasible.)

Well you can't make up your own rules. How would it work for the compiler or the developer using your public api if a function returned an unknown type that they don't have access too? I think you should read the whole chapter on Access Control and not just the paragraph I linked to so you understand how it works.

@JoakimDanielson Ok,I'll take a look at everything not only Protocol Conformance, thanks

It doesn’t make sense to make it private and let it be returned. How are the functions receiving the value supposed to use/know what it is.

Edited:  @loremipsum What I aimed to accomplish was to abstract the protocol type, which I managed to do successfully. Additionally, since this code adheres to functional programming principles, I sought to make the inner part of the struct abstract yet usable within the methods. It seems like this approach may not have been the best choice.

You cannot hide the types you use to conform to a protocol. This is mostly due to a limitation in some types that will possibly be lifted in the future. There is no way in Swift today to express "the opaque type that me.f() returns is the same opaque type that me.g() accepts." If that existed, you could do this entirely with opaque types, but you doesn't and you can't.
The most important document for this discussion is Improving the UI of Generics. If you're interested in these topics, you should start there to get your footing in what is "because it's not implemented" vs "because it's impossible." You will also want to read the urtext on the topic, the Generics Manifesto.
There is second limitation in Swift that blocks your specific attempt to implement this, and that is that individual cases of an enum type cannot be more restrictive than the entire type. Again, this could be possible, but it is not. So you cannot expose the return type as an enum without exposing its internal workings.
This is one of many cases where Swift favors structs over enums, even though they should be duals. With structs, this is straightforward, if requiring one layer of indirection.
I will use the following protocol which is a bit more Swift-like in its naming (though this is a deeply un-Swifty approach, as I'll discuss later).
I've made this protocol public because if it's internal the rest of the question is irrelevant. There is absolutely no problem with a type conforming in any way it likes to a protocol an outside caller cannot see.
public protocol RationalAlgebra {
    associatedtype RationalValue

    static func makeFrac(_ x: Int, _ y: Int) throws -> RationalValue
    static func add(_ r1: RationalValue, _ r2: RationalValue) -> RationalValue
    static func toString(_ r: RationalValue) -> String
}

With this, you can create your own "opaque type" using a struct that exposes nothing:
public struct Rational: RationalAlgebra {

    // Rational.RationalValue is public, but exposes no internal details.
    // It exists only as "the RationalAlgebra type that Rational returns."
    public struct RationalValue {
        private enum Value {
            case Whole(Int)
            case Frac(Int, Int)
        }
        private let value: Value
    }

    private let value: RationalValue

    public static func makeFrac(_ x: Int, _ y: Int) throws -> RationalValue { fatalError() }

    public static func add(_ r1: RationalValue, _ r2: RationalValue) -> RationalValue { fatalError() }

    public static func toString(_ r: RationalValue) -> String { fatalError() }

    fileprivate func foo(_ x: Int) { fatalError() }

    private func boo(_ x: Int) -> Int { fatalError() }
}

All of this is deeply "un-Swifty" for many reasons. One is that the protocol is doing no work. Protocols are not meaningless "abstraction layers" like the pimpl pattern in C++ or the Impl pattern in Java. Protocols exist to allow algorithms to be written over heterogeneous types. If your protocol and your conforming type have exactly the same shape, then you're probably just playing with types rather than using them as a real tool. (Fun, yes, but not the point.)
This is also extremely un-Swifty in that it a type that relies entirely on static methods. See BinaryInteger as a starting point for how you should think about "Rational."
But even so, your underlying goal of hiding the details (if not the name) of a returned type is completely possible. It is just not easily accomplished with enums because Swift likes structs better.

// Define a protocol for rational number operations
internal protocol RATIONAL {
    associatedtype rational
    
    // Method to create a rational number from numerator and denominator
    static func makeFrac(_ x: Int, _ y: Int) throws -> rational
    
    // Method to add two rational numbers
    static func add(_ r1: rational, _ r2: rational) -> rational
    
    // Method to convert a rational number to a string representation
    static func toString(_ r: rational) -> String
}

// A concrete implementation of the RATIONAL protocol
public struct Rational1: RATIONAL {
    // Define a typealias for the rational type
    public typealias rational = (Int, Int)
    
    // Method to create a rational number from numerator and denominator
    public static func makeFrac(_ x: Int, _ y: Int) throws -> rational {
        // Implementation goes here
    }
    
    // Internal method to create a rational number from numerator and denominator
    internal func makeFrac(_ x: Int, _ y: Int) throws -> (Int, Int) {
        // Implementation goes here
    }
    
    // Method to add two rational numbers
    public static func add(_ r1: rational, _ r2: rational) -> rational {
        // Implementation goes here
    }
    
    // Internal method to add two rational numbers
    internal func add(_ r1: (Int, Int), _ r2: (Int, Int)) -> (Int, Int) {
        // Implementation goes here
    }

    // Method to convert a rational number to a string representation
    public static func toString(_ r: rational) -> String {
        // Implementation goes here
    }
    
    // Internal method to convert a rational number to a string representation
    internal func toString(_ r: (Int, Int)) -> String {
        // Implementation goes here
    }
    
    // Fileprivate utility method
    fileprivate func foo(_ x: Int) {
        // Implementation goes here
    }
    
    // Private utility method
    private func boo(_ x: Int) -> Int {
        // Implementation goes here
    }
}

This is the best I could come up with because typealias is immutable, and also I removed the enum.
Btw typealias can be internal this time but looks like it was not the case in the first place (with the first approach).
